# Calculate the amount of hours Libreoffice calc formula

Tags: libreoffice-calc

Hi I would like to calculate the amount of hours between few pairs of time where ';' is separator. I know how to do it by spliting it but I would like to avoid this and do it in one cell. For example from `8:00-12:00;13:30-16:00;16:30-17:15` cell should display 7,25 or 7:15. Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this

```
Function Total_Time(sList As String) As String 
Dim aTemp As Variant, aPair As Variant
Dim i As Long, dRes As Double 
    aTemp = Split(sList, ";")
    For i = LBound(aTemp) To UBound(aTemp)
        aPair = Split(aTemp(i), "-")
        dRes = dRes + TimeValue(aPair(1))
        dRes = dRes - TimeValue(aPair(0))
    Next i
    Total_Time = Format(dRes,"HH:MM")
End Function
```

Comment: This works pretty well. It is exactly what I wanted. Thank you.